# Wordpress Plugin for Public to Create Domain Email Address?

Tags: wordpress, apache, cpanel, mail-server

Q: Is there a way to connect the mail server to the front end using Cpanel and Wordpress?

A: Of Course There Is!!!!

Q: Does anyone know of a way to do it? Particularly something easy I can portal into a page,widget or snippet? I want to make sure anyone can create an email address on my domain without me being involved?

A: No chance in Hell.

Any thoughts? Mail server portal to create domain email addresses via a wordpress plugin or an outside universe plugin for cpanel?

Comment: its interesting to me how I can master all of my mailer.php scenarios inside cpanel and wordpress.................. BUTTTT!!!........... How little I know about the other parts of the mail server language.

Comment: IFRAME's a Doozy!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question. The short answer is no. Porting cPanel functionality through WordPress is not exactly a one-person job.